# How to resolve multilanguaes for social bots?

Tags: php, facebook, session, social-networking

I have done multi languages on my web site.
When user visits page at first time works mechanism that detects country and language.

After is occurring reloading page and data is added to current session.
Problem is that when I try to share links in social networks I get empty data, because social bot does not have session mechanism therefore web server returns empty page without text.

How I can resolve this issue or may be change something in architecture.
To share please a good prartic about this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use sessions for this. If you want to share the page URL with the right language, make sure this language is part of the URL. A simple way to do this is to use a query string. Your URL could look like this: `http://www.example.com/page?language=dutch`
In PHP you can use `$_GET` to read which language to use:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['language'] ) ) {
    // Display page in specified language
} else {
    // Display page in default language
}
```